# \res\menu\main.xml:5: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i change my Google APls [Android 4.0] to Android [2.2] at first i have an error in values-v11 from android:Theme.Holo.Light i change it to  
and values-v14  to  and it look likes no error but the menu from res folder got this error. On the item.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.klk.kidslearningkey.Main" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

thank you so much .

Comment: showAsAction is introduced in API11

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Android Actionbar link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

under the title "Using XML attributes from the support library"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  tools:context="com.klk.kidslearningkey.Main" >

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```